# NAT port forwarding from host to client in VMWare Fusion 5?

Tags: vmware

How do I forward ports from my host machine to the virtualized machine when I'm using NAT to share my network connection? I found some instructions for earlier versions of VMWare, but I don't see the files they mention in the same location in my installation.

Comment: I found some conflicting help answers http://communities.vmware.com/message/1984094 http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2003463

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Okay, I found out where it's located - `/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/nat.conf`

So, open it up (VMWare shouldn't be running while you do this):

```
sudo nano /Library/Preferences/VMware\ Fusion/vmnet8/nat.conf
```

Go down in the file, there should be a section like:

```
[incomingtcp]

# Use these with care - anyone can enter into your VM through these...
# The format and example are as follows:
#<external port number> = <VM's IP address>:<VM's port number>
#35 = 172.16.126.128:22
```

Uncomment that last line, and edit as appropriate.

Couple of notes:

- These instructions are for TCP port forwarding, there's a corresponding `[incomingudp]` section for UDP
- If for some reason this section doesn't already exist, just add it

Comment: Looks confirmed in the official documentation: http://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_network21.html

Comment: So this is a global setting that affects _all_ virtual machines?

Comment: @SargeBorsch You specify the IP of the VM that forwarding is configured for.

Comment: and then restart vmware network: `sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --stop;
    sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --start`

Answer (score 6):

Based on the VMWare knowledge base.

> The following commands can be used to update the changes without
>   restarting Fusion 4.x and later. These can be used if you not want to
>   relaunch Fusion, if you have other Virtual Machines running.

```
sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --stop
sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --start
```

Make sure you skip the --configure step as it will reset the nat.conf file to defaults.

Source:
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1026510

Comment: This isn't a complete solution in and of itself, but is a very useful addition to the other answer given. Perhaps it should be an edit to the other answer, or have the other answer's content added here (with credit, of course), to have a single answer that covers the complete steps?